# Coredata change database on AppStore Update

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I have an app that's currently available in the AppStore and I'm building it from scratch for the next update.
In the current "live" app I'm using CoreData as well as in the "new" app. My problem appears when trying to put the new app, over the old one (app crashes at launch). The new database is totally different from the old one, with no connection between them (the current code has no reference to the old DB). Is there a way of ignoring/removing completely the old database in the new app when updating? How do I tell CoreData to use the new models, without having the old models in the new app?

Comment: How did you create the new model in the project? Is the old model still in the project? Are you trying to do any migration? Do you have any code to deal with the old data store file? Is the new data store file in the same place as the old one?

Comment: The store file is in a different place, with a different name. This is a new project from scratch, so all the models from the old app are not present.

Comment: @Wain this is how I initiate the new persistent store: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4m8dmi9q3kxnvlc/persistent_store.rtf?dl=0

Comment: @Wain there is currently no code connected to the old data store file. Any suggestion?

Comment: It would help if you edit your question to add the full text of any error messages you receive. App crashes are generally accompanied by explanatory information which describes the problem.

Comment: Are you merging all models from the bundle in the code? I don't recall if it's guaranteed that old files not present in a new bundle are deleted from the device.